# What does the word "enterprise" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

"For now, the focus at Clear Labs is on indexing for the enterprise, one that includes creating a future where food brands can be proactive rather than reactive to outbreaks or recalls."

Here's [the original article](http://techcrunch.com/2015/09/15/clear-labs-aims-to-be-google-search-for-gmos-in-our-packaged-food/#.n1eslf:PcCS).

I suppose it can mean "project" but I am not sure.

Comment: "Enterprise" means a business (or possibly large governmental or charitable organization).  It's a (somewhat worn out) buzzword in the computer biz.

Comment: As to "proactive", look it up.  (It's another buzzword.)

Comment: This is marketingbabbleblahblah for "*send Clear Labs your business*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context, it means Clear Labs is currently focusing on **(large) companies**, as opposed to consumers:

> The idea is interesting. Though Clear Labs is mostly for testing at **large food brands** right now, it could have **consumer applications**...
>
> The co-founders prognosticate **a consumer application** around five to 7 years in the future...
>
> For now, the focus at Clear Labs is on indexing **for the enterprise**...

"Enterprise" can be defined as:

> enterprise: a company, organization, or business

([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/enterprise))

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you please explain the second part of the sentence as well, i.e "proactive rather than reactive to outbreaks or recalls"

Comment: Glad I could help. Please ask a separate question regarding the second part of the sentence.